# Is there a way to load he page only after all the data are fetched in angular?

Tags: angular, pageload

I am working on an angular project with landing pages. So when I integrate with the apis for different graphs on that page. But in initial loading, the datas are not fetched before the page is loaded i have to refresh the page several times to get the data. Is there any way to load the page only after the data is loaded?

Comment: show us some code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) so the routing will only occur after the data is fetched.

Comment: you can fetch the data on component initialisation but add a loading indicator. Or you can use APP_INITIALIZER so the application itself will only be boostraped once the data is fetched.